# Send Ctrl+Z to serial port via command line

Tags: command-line, serial-port, ctrl

I am trying to send the following to the COM1 serial port via command line using ECHO or similar (I've also tried downloading a small program called serialsend, but I am stuck with how to send the equivalent of <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>. This is to send a SMS message via a Siemens TC35 GAM module. I am able to do it via Hyperterminal as a test and it works fine, but I cannot figure out how to send the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> at the end to confirm the ned of the message.

This is what I have:

```
AT

AT+CMGF=1

AT+CMSG="+xxxxxxxxxxx"

HELLO
```

Now, after Hello, which is the message I want to send, I have to send <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>. But cannot figure out how to do it, I have tried this:

```
AT

AT+CMGF=1

AT+CMSG="+xxxxxxxxxxx"

HELLO

\x1A
```

As I read somehwere that this would be the equivalent of doing it, but it hasnt worked.

Can anyone help me with this? I have found solutions, but they are not command line, which is what I need.

I have also tried using this format:

```
ECHO AT > COM1:
```

But as I don't know how to send <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> I don't know if it is working.

Comment: Thank you for answering, but I do not know how to send this from command line or via ECHO, can you help with this? Thanks

Comment: I assumed you were a programmer.  Post to superuser.com instead.

Comment: you might get more help if you include a tag on your question for what OS you are using. I assume a windows version, due to your use of all-caps command name 'ECHO'. Many power users filter questions by tags, so adding a windows or batch file tag may get you the help you need. good luck.

Comment: Did you trying pressing the `CTRL+Z` keys on the keyboard?

Answer (score 4):

I wrote the free command line program SerialSend that you mentioned. Since this question was originally posted, I've added an extra feature that allows arbitrary byte values to be included (in hex format) in the text you're sending via the serial port. For example, to send Ctrl-Z (26 decimal, 0x1A hex), just use the following command:

```
SerialSend /hex "\x1a"
```

Port name/number, baudrate, etc can be configured with additional command line arguments. For example,

```
SerialSend /baudrate 9600 /devnum 2 /hex "\x1a"
```

For more details, see the [SerialSend home page](http://batchloaf.wordpress.com/serialsend/).

Hope that helps!

Ted

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
port.Write(txt_msgbox.Text + char.ConvertFromUtf32(26));
```

It works :)

Answer (score 0):

type this command Serial.println((char)26); in Arduino code ... one square box will appear on serial monitor. Copy that square and paste in Notepad++. It will be displayed as SUB with black background. wheneever you want to type cntrl+z, just copy this SUB and paste in serial monitor. It works.

Answer (score 0):

At my system with usb gsm modem works next script:

```bash
$ cat sendsms

    #!/bin/bash
    #usage: sendsms <mobile number> <text to send>
    printf "AT+CMGF=1\r\nAT+CMGS=\"$1\"\r\n$2\x1a" > /dev/ttyUSB3
```

As you can see, `printf` sends <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> as `\x1a`